# Whats wrong with this RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, lazy-evaluation

I wrote this RegEx: `'/\[\.{2}([^\.].+)\]/'`

And it is supposed to match patterns like this: `[..Class,Method,Parameter]`

It works until I have a pattern like this: `[..Class1,Method1,Para1][..Class2,Method2,Para2]`

I tried to make the RegEx lazy by putting a `?` behin the `+`. `'/\[\.{2}([^\.].+?)\]/'` but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add a `+` so it's 1 or many: `(\[\.{2}([^\.].+)\])+`

Comment: What about `[^\]]+` instead of `.+`?

Comment: Note that `/\[\.{2}([^\.].+?)\]/` should work, except if you have something like `[..]` or `[..a]` *(zero or a single character before the closing bracket and after the two dots)* in the string. As an aside, you don't have to escape the dot inside a character class and the closing square bracket isn't a special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wanted to use `[^\.]+` rather than `[\.].+`. Note that `.+` is a greedily quantified dot pattern and matches *any* 1 or more chars other than line break chars, and thus matches across both `]` and `[`.

Match any 1 or more chars other than `]` with `[^]]` rather than using `[^\.]`:

```
\[\.{2}([^]]+)]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3QEz67/1)

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\.{2}` - two dot chars
- `([^]]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `]` (no need to escape `]` when it is the first char in a character class)
- `]` - a closing bracket (no need to escape `]` when it is outside a character class).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/J3vlvn):

```
$str = '[..Class,Method,Parameter]  [..Class1,Method1,Para1][..Class2,Method2,Para2]';
preg_match_all('/\[\.{2}([^\.].+?)\]/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [..Class,Method,Parameter]
    [1] => [..Class1,Method1,Para1]
    [2] => [..Class2,Method2,Para2]
)
```

Comment: _“rather than using `[^\.]`”_ — isn’t that a different, unrelated test? Shouldn’t that be “rather than using `.+`”?

Comment: @Xufox I think `.` is a typo (the one after `[^\.]`). OP wanted to use `[^\.]+`, but it might not actually be the solution if there are `.` chars inside the brackets.

Comment: Thank you, that worked pefectly! You safed my day (:

Comment: Note that `[^\.]` is equivalent to `[^.]`, as `.` matches a literal dot character when it appears within square brackets.